# Boost::multi_index_container with disparate key and element types

Tags: c++, boost-multi-index

Is it possible to use different type data structures for keys and elements in a boost::multi_index_container? GCC lets me compile something like this:

```
struct StructA {
  std::string name;
};

struct StructB {
  int primary;
  int secondary;
};

using mic = 
multi_index_container<
  StructA,
  indexed_by<
    composite_key< 
      StructB,
      member< StructB, int, StructB::primary >,
      member< StructB, int, StructB::secondary >
>>>;
```

First, I'm not sure if the above code violates any sort of multi_index_container usage. It certainly compiles with different element (StructA) and composite index key (StructB). Second, how do I insert/emplace into such a container? Third, how do I access elements in such a container?

Answer (score 0):

How do *you* think this is supposed to work?